# Луна -- с заглавной или со строчной буквы?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Вы желаете, чтобы ваши волосы росли быстрее?
Тогда подстригайтесь в период растущей луны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Луна пишется с прописной буквы только как астрономическое тело. Во всех остальных случаях пишется со строчной, но художественная литература и астрологические источники могут использовать прописную букву в качестве этакого фетиша. Это не соответствует нормам русского языка, но такая практика существует.
Само собой, что растущая и ущербная луна — это из области астрологии. Тут правильно использовать строчную букву.
На всякий случай пояснение: прописная буква — это большая, строчная — это маленькая.